# Alterar formato de data no Django para dd/mm/yy

Tags: python, django, data, django-rest-framework

Olá! Eu to tentando criar uma aplicação com Django Rest para um desafio de estágio. Mas eu me deparo com um problema que não será tolerado. Preciso que a data inserida no DateField responda ao padrão brasileiro DD/MM/YYYY, mas só consigo alterá-lo para MM/DD/YY no máximo.

Meu models da app core:

```
from django.db import models
from organizadores.models import Organizadore


# Create your models here.
class Evento(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organizadores = models.ManyToManyField(Organizadore)
    data_inicio = models.DateField(null=False)
    data_fim = models.DateField(null=False)
    confirmado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Settings do projeto:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@0z5o*9z7hd6@b-=_3w!x+i)bg^0*q#q!qw258wvsp(jq(2-r$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'core',
    'organizadores'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eventos.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eventos.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

Como está nas configurações, já tentei usar o `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`, `USE_L1ON = False` e não consigo de jeito nenhum achar como editar isso. Já vi pessoas sugerindo usar `DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)`, mas essas kwargs não existem e apontam erro no código:
`widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`

Não sei mais o que fazer, já tentei mudar a linguagem pra pt-br, en-uk e en-GB, mas em nenhum caso funciona. Alguém consegue ter uma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendo de Django, mas:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

Em "settings.py" talvez resolva o seu problema.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.

Answer (score 0):

Tem duas formas de resolver isso:

Uma é definir o formato globalmente do date, datetime e outros no settings.py (veja a [documentação](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date_format)):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_FORMAT': "%d/%m/%Y",
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%d-%m-%Y"],
    ....
}
```

Ou definir especificamente no campo do serializer:

```
data_inicio = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y', 'iso-8601'])`
```